# Passing correct jQuery selector to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I am writing a jQuery plugin which, ideally I would like in it's own namespace.

So far, this seems to work (in terms of namespace nesting)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.nspace = {
        foo: function() {
            // Does not work becuase $(this) is not the correct selector.
            $(this).show();
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

So given then example above, I might call my function like so:

```
$("html, body").nspace.foo();
```

but `$(this)` is not `[html, body]`...How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** To clarify (based on user comments)...

`$("html, body").nspace.foo();` should call foo for `[html, body]` but, `$(this)` inside nspace resolves to nspace...so it's trying to call `nspace.foo();`

Comment: It's not clear to me what is not working. Can you be more specific on what you are expecting to have in foo() function?
Based on you code, $(this).show() will be called 2 times: first time $('html').show(), and second time $('body').show().

Comment: @Draykos, my point is that $(this) is not [html, body] when called from $("html, body").nspace.foo(). $(this) in this context is the object (nspace), so it's essentially trying to do nspace.foo();

Comment: $(this) in this context is foo object.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do this, but just because I dislike when someone says "You can't" in programming (often untrue, especially in Javascript) - here's how you could do this:

The jQuery object is constructed each time using its prototype.init function, which is aliased to fn.init, so you could overwrite it with a wrapped function that adds your namespace object in a way that doesn't harm any existing usage or libraries, like so:

```
(function($) {
    var baseInit = $.fn.init;
    $.fn.init = function(selector, context, rootjQuery) {
        // Instantiate jQuery the way it expects
        var j = new baseInit(selector, context, rootjQuery);

        // Add our extra object/namespace
        // Use j inside to refer to the current jQuery object
        j.nspace = {
            foo: function() {
                j.show();
            }
        };

        // Return it all and other libraries are none the wiser
        return j;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/7TPZY/

Comment: Thanks, this works! Just wondering why you "shouldn't" do this? The reason I wanted the plugin organised into its own 'namespace' was because: 1, the plugin adds rather a lot to jQuery. 2, the new features are all related, so it made sense to namespace them. 3, some of the new functionality might use the same names as jQuery functions (position() for example).

Comment: And another thing, using your example in VS2012, if I try to call j.each(function() { $(this).click(); }); It works, but VS intellisense does not display jQuery functions when I call $(this). Any ideas why?

Comment: Well it's not that big of a deal but basically every time someone calls $('blah') they're running your code to add your namespace and functions to their object. It's a minor performance hit but there is one, anyway.

Comment: @series0ne I tested this in VS2012 and it does in fact get Intellisense for j. Are you remembering to add ///<reference path="~/ui/jquery-1.9.1.js"/> or whatever the path is to jquery at the top of your JS file? Or maybe you mean elsewhere - throw a jsfiddle together and add a comment where things aren't working?

Comment: @series0ne I see now; yes the extra layer is confusing the VS JS Intellisense parser; you'd likely need to add a -vsdoc.js with VsDoc comments to help it along.

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look into that. Also, I have a copy of JetBrains WebStorm, so I am going to try the same thing in there and see what happens as it's intellisense engine is far superior to VS.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the classic pattern for a jQuery plugin: define only one method: in your case, nspace. Inside this method, you'll take every case into account. Sounds hard, but it's pretty easy once you've looked into [that](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).
(By the way you definitely have to look at that when writing a jQuery plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an object as a plugin and still get the jQuery object that was used to get the object. You simply have no reference to that jQuery object when you call a method in your object.

Put the function directly as the plugin:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.nspace = function() {
    this.show();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$("html, body").nspace();
```

(Note that the object is the jQuery instance, not a selector or an element, so you don't need to use `$(this)`).

Comment: That works, but is defeats the namespace, so I would have to add ugly parenthesis, like so: $("selector").nspace().foo();

Comment: @series0ne: Yes, you simply can't namespace plugins that way (unless you use a property getter, but those are not supported in all browsers).